# python pdfkit preserve datetimestamp

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit library in python to convert html files to pdf. The code is as follows:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_file("test.html", "test.pdf")
```

Now the date modified/created for "test.pdf" will be the time I ran the Python script.

Is there a way to make the date modified for "test.pdf" the same as "test.html"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something like this:

```
import os
s = os.stat("test.html")
os.utime("test.pdf", (s.st_atime, s.st_mtime))
```